# POST-COMMIT SCRIPT of SVN to check commit log for PRODUCT-ID using shell script

Tags: svn

I am new to Linux as well as for Subversion. I had a task to check the syntax of the commit message to contain PRODUCT ID. If its not present I have pass a message to user saying an invalid format using SHELL SCRIPT.
Below are the steps I had followed after a lot search in google,
For the PRE-COMMIT hook the code is:

```
#!/bin/sh  
set -e  
/PATH-TO-REPOSITORY/hooks/CommentSyntax.sh "$1" "$2"
```

My CommentSyntax.sh script is,

```
#!/bin/sh  
REPOS="$1"  
TXN="$2"  
SVNLOOK=/usr/bin/svnlook  
regex="PRODUCT-[0-9]*"  
if [ `"$SVNLOOK" log -t "$TXN" "$REPOS"` =~ ${regex} ]; then  
    exit 0  
else  
  echo "" 1>&2    
  echo "Please make your commit comment start with PRODUCT-XXX" 1>&2  
  exit 1  
fi
```

Whenever I am trying to check-in the code, am getting the below error,

```
srikanth:~/testing$ svn ci -m "PRODUCT-123"
Sending        two.java
Transmitting file data .svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:
[: 22: PRODUCT-123: unexpected operator

Please make your commit comment start with PRODUCT-XXX
```

I am not sure where I gone wrong. Request your valuable advice on the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test command knows no `=~` operator. Relpace the

```
if [ `"$SVNLOOK" log -t "$TXN" "$REPOS"` =~ ${regex} ]; then
```

line by

```
if "$SVNLOOK" log -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | head -n1 | grep -q '^PRODUCT-[0-9][0-9]*' ; then
```

`head -n1` select the first line of the commit, `grep` checks the regexp.

Comment: Hi Rudi, Thanks for the infomration. I had modified the script as per your suggestion, and below is the output I had received,  `srikanth:~/testing$ svn ci -m "PRODUCT-123"                  Sending        two.java                                  Transmitting file data .svn: Commit failed (details follow):  
svn: Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output: /<PATHTOREPO>/hooks/checkCommentSyntax.sh: 13: PRODUCT-123: not found                                                          Please make your commit comment start with PRODUCT-XXX`

Comment: @Srikanth Argh, I just now saw that you have backticks(\`) around the `svnlook` command. When you enclose parts of a shell script with backticks, the shell runs the command, and fill the text, which the command wrote on stdout, into the next to be executed command. Here this means that the commit message would be interpreted as the next command, but you want the commit message piped into the following programs. I removed the backticks, so that the command now should work.

Comment: Hi Rudi, thanks a lot. It worked fine. Now I am working on to improve the script to do some more commit checks.

Comment: Hi Rudi, One more issue I had faced when moving further, I had to limit this syntax checking pre-commit hook for only one branch. Any suggestion how to achieve this? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Srikanth You can use `svnlook changed` to get the changed paths. BTW: you can accept an answer when it solves your problem. Also should you add @username in a comment since SO by default only notifies the questioner and the author of an answer of a new comment.

Comment: @Rudi, Thanks for guiding me. I am unable to find option to accept an answer and hence I had replied to you with thanks. Sorry for the inconvience. Request to let me know how to accept answer as you had already resolved my problem. Thank you

Comment: @Rudi,I had acccepted the answer by clicking the tick mark on left side panel of your first answer. Sorry for my dumbness. Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: @Srikanth No problem, It's always hard to get the details a new platform.